# Pentagons cutting

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to cut a pentagon into two equal pentagons?

Pentagons are not neccesarily convex as otherwise it would be trivially impossible.

I was given this problem at a contest but cannot figure the solution out, can somebody help?

Edit: Buy "cut" I mean "describe as a union of two pentagons which intersect only on the boudaries".

Comment: Do you mean cut with a straight line? Is it even possible to cut a pentagon into two pentagons? It seems you always end up with a four sided shape once you cut?

Comment: Interesting problem, it seems if starting from a shape like this (skewed more to the right side) http://www.quia.com/files/quia/users/ander1rk/concave_polygon.gif  and put another instance into triangular recess it is at least almost possible.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog Sorry for the ambiguity, edited the post.

Comment: Equal as in equal areas or congruent?

Comment: Congruent of course, eq. areas is not interesting at all.

Comment: not the same question, and perhaps not even closely related, but it is about cutting pentagons with just one straight line http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath060/kmath060.htm

Comment: @strrrr : an image to construct or dissaprove the solution added

Answer (score 2):

I tried playing around with this on a image editor and I realized that it is not possible. Two of the interior angles will be explementary and two will be supplementary, due to the cut starting on an edge and the requirement of an inner vertex, as John has said. These four angles add up to $540^\circ$, which is the sum of all five interior angles of a pentagon. Therefore the last angle will be $0^\circ$, which is impossible. Therefore the cut is impossible.

Comment: Ahh, very good!  You hit on it, and I actually stated as much in my answer (5th and 6th statements!) but didn't recognize that that was the answer!  Just one minor tweak in terminology: complementary angles add up to 90 degrees.  Explementary angles add up to 360 degrees.  (I edited this one word and gave +1.)

Answer (score 1):

A few observations that constrain any possible answer:

- Your cut must start on a vertex and end on a side, and must have one internal vertex in between.  Otherwise, you won't get two pentagons with the cut.
- Because of the internal vertex, the two pentagons must be convex.
- Because the two pentagons after the cut are convex, the original pentagon must be convex  I'm *suspecting* only one reflex angle, but I'm not sure.  If my suspicion is correct, then the cut must start at this reflex angle, and one of the resulting angles must be reflex.
- The sum of the interior angles will be $540$ degrees.
- Two of the angles will be supplementary (from the intersection on the edge).
- The sum of two of the angles will be $360$ degrees (from the internal angle created by the cut).
- The sum of the two angles created at the vertex of the original pentagon will be equal to the angle at that vertex.

Comment: I do not agree with your second and third (whenever disstract convex shape from convex the remainder is concave) IMHO if solution exists, it is two of congruent concave pentagons, however turnd over in 3rd dimension.

Comment: @z100 If you agree with my first statement, then that vertex creates a reflex angle.  As for the third statement, intersection with one of the sides will create two angles less than 180 degrees, as will intersection with a vertex of an interior angle less than 180 degrees.

Comment: one reflex angle is enough for a polygon not to be convex ... otherwise you and strrrr are right, sumarizing internal angles in one of small pentagons and sumarizing angles in entire pentagon leads to conclusion that one angle (most right in the sketch) is equal 0 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** try from brief sketch or prove it is not possible
[image]

Comment: Tempting, but on a plane it won't work via cheesyfluff's answer. Tge angles cannot all be exactly equal. Could work in spherical geometry though.